# HelloGoogleMap runtime crash

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to run the HelloGoogleMaps App from Tutorials with Android 4.0.3.

I got this from the Console, everything seemed fine until:

```
Uploading HelloGoogleMaps.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-01-31 16:05:29 - HelloGoogleMaps] Installing HelloGoogleMaps.apk...
[2012-01-31 16:05:45 - HelloGoogleMaps] Success!
[2012-01-31 16:05:46 - HelloGoogleMaps] Starting activity      net.examples.HelloGoogleMaps.HelloGoogleMapsActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-01-31 16:05:48 - HelloGoogleMaps] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent {    act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=net.examples.HelloGoogleMaps/.HelloGoogleMapsActivity }
```

At this point, emulator shows "Unfortunately, your app did not run...." and in LogCat, I am seeing this:

```
01-31 15:56:50.702: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've also cleaned, closed and reopened the project to no avail.

Comment: please see in your Manifest file .
Have you define second activity(MapActivity)

Comment: Yes, in my Manifest file, within Application, I have one Activity with defined name as "HelloGoogleActivity".

Comment: make sure you have added user library inside of application tag

Answer (score 0):

Have you extends your activity to extends MapActivity {

Give proper permission into manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps" android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

for your main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key goes here"
/>
```

I think there is problem.
if you want more please share your code...

Comment: Did you get the solution for this ?